# Using TeXcount with TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, texcount

I am trying to run TeXcount with TeXnicCenter on Windows but cannot find any clear instructions as to how to do this. I have so far installed active perl and TeXcount. In TeXnicCenter I have defined an output profile `Latex => Word count`.

Under the LaTeX tab I have:

- Run (La)TeX in this profile - unticked
- Do not use BibTeX in this profile - ticked
- Do not use MakeIndex in this profile - ticked.

In the Postprocessor tab I have:

- Processors: `TeXcount`
- Executable: `C:\WINDOWS\TeXcount_2_3\texcount.pl`
- Arguments: `"%pm"`

In the Viewer tab I have:

- Executable path: `C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE`
- View project's output; Command line argument checked; Command `"bm.wc"`

Running this profile on my LaTeX document doesn't produce any output (or error messages) so I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

I've also attempted to use the version of texcount with the MikTex installation setup as above. This runs and opens notepad with the error

> Cannot find the C:...*.wc file. Do you want to create a new file?

The file created is empty. In the output profile the following error occurs:

> texcount length() used on %warnings (did you mean "scalar(keys %warnings)"? at C:...\texcount.pl line 2221

Comment: Could you, please, add into your question, why you do not use the `texcount` (both as `.pl` and `.exe`), already included in MiKTeX and TeX Live?

Comment: @Mark You can ignore the `texcount length() used on %warnings (d` business: I get the same but do see output. Does `texcount` work from the Command Line? One thing I don't get is how you are expecting the output of `texcount` to get to your Notepad file.