# How do I get TeXCount working in TeXnicCenter

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, word-count

Sorry this is a bit specific, but I could really use some help.
I am trying to work out a good way of getting a word count for my thesis. I do most of my editing on windows, via TeXnicCenter v1 and MikTeX2.9.

The TeXCount webpage implies that MikTeX should come with TeXCount installed, and I see texcount.exe under `C:\ProgramFiles\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` but I don't understand how to use it.

I have seen the following question [Using TeXcount with TeXnicCenter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108392/using-texcount-with-texniccenter) on this site, but I decided to go down the route suggested on this thread
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=730 because it seemed to me some folks had actually got it working, but it hasn't helped me yet.

I followed the instructions

1. Install ActivePerl
2. in TeXnicCenter go to /Tools/Customize/tools/new(insert)/
3. Fill in:
   WordCount
   command: "cmd /K texcount"
   Arguments: "-inc '%pm'"

At this point it seems to try to run MiKTeX 2.8 but I have no idea why! And then throws up an error message saying "The Perl script could not be found."

I am not surprised, I can't find it either. It is not installed in `MiKTeX 2.9\scripts`. I have downloaded it myself and put `TeXcount_3_0_0_24` into that directory, but I am not confident that this path is being scanned by MiKTeX, and again I am not sure how to make that happen. I tried putting it elsewhere and providing MiKTeX with a new location, but MiKTeX just told me it was "Not a TDS-compliant root directory".

I am rather stumped. I don't want to have to go putting copies of perl scripts and executables into all my directories as the final post suggested.

Alternatively, if you think I am crazy to be going down this route, can anyone recommend a free pdf word counting tool? I'd prefer texcount because my word limit does not include captions, references etc and it's a faff to strip them out.

As a last resort I can ftp everything across to linux and try to install TeXCount there, but I'd prefer to stick with my laptop if I can.

Comment: I just tried pointing `command: texcount.exe` where I point to the executable in `miktex2.9\bin` and now it just says "file not found". It seemed to do some kind of package installation step, but I still see no sign of the .pl anywhere

Comment: I just installed texcount with the miktex package and it worked out-of-box without problem (but it didn't like text after \end{document}). Adding scripts manually should normally not be necessary in miktex. Imho "cmd /K texcount" in texniccenter is wrong. Use simply "texcount" as command and `-inc %pm` as argument. Also I certainly would never try an installation instruction that is more than 7 years old.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I agree it's too old, but I had no clue where to start. Anyway, I have changed my "tool settings" to match yours, but now it says `no file specified`. Progress at least, it looks like it is actually trying to run texcount even if it is not finding my file.

Comment: I put double quotes around `"%pm"` and now it seems to run, but a box pops up for 0.2 seconds, I can't see what it's saying because it then closes instantly. I have used `-html` and `>texcount.html` but the resulting file is blank. Guess I need to know how to forward stderr to a file under windows!

Comment: I didn't test texcount in texniccenter (which I don't use) but on the command line. I don't know what you should do in texniccenter to see the output of the command line. Redirection to a file should work with `%pm >texcount.log`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your help. I have got it working at a command prompt, for some reason the redirection to an html via TeXnicCenter wasn't working at all, and it wouldn't keep the command prompt up. I uninstalled MiKTex8 as it was obviously screwing with the default path. I now have some output!

Comment: For the MiKTeX part see [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158796).

Answer (score 5):

I guess I will answer my question, although it isn't solved as such - but at least I can use TeXcount on windows via what seems to me a very linuxy method!

1. I installed ActivePerl
2. I have MikTex installed which has texcount.exe as listed in the question
3. I hunted around for texcount.pl but still haven't found it - which makes me wonder whether the executable actually contains compiled perl?
4. I did attempt to run the commands as stated in the original question, and MiKTex did claim to be doing a package install, but I stopped watching so I don't know what it actually did!

Anyway, the outcome is that I can now fire up a command prompt, go to the directory containing my tex file, and run `texcount -html my_file.tex >my_file_wc.html` and get sensible readable output.

Answer (score 1):

The original TeXcount is a Perl script, which would typically be called `texcount.pl` (or with version codes attached). To run this, you need Perl installed: ActivePerl and StrawberryPerl are two popular options on Windows. Apart from this, TeXcount requires no installation: the `texcount.pl` Perl script is entirely self-contained.

As Ulrike Fisher has pointed out, the `texcount.exe` file is just a wrapper for calling `texcount.pl`. MiKTeX has TeXcount version 3.0 (latest release); in my MiKTeX installation, I only find TeXcount version 2.3, but my MiKTeX may be dated. You can run `texcount -ver` to check the version, but that shouldn't be the problem.

If you have downloaded the script from the [TeXcount web site](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/index.html) as `texcount_3_0_0_24.pl`, you might want to rename it `texcount.pl`, or next time when you upgrade to a new version you'll have all references pointing to the older version.

When you're trying to run TeXcount, be that `texcount.exe` or `texcount.pl`, you may need to specify the full path or add the location to the PATH environment variable. In some cases, you might also have to execute the Perl script using `perl texcount.pl` if the file type `.pl` is not associated with Perl.

If you run TeXcount using the command `texcount` only, I suspect it is the `texcount.exe` executable that is being run.

If you are running TeXcount from within another program (e.g. TeXnicCenter) and the piping to file using `texcount ... > outfile` causes problems, as I know it does with some applications, you can use the `-out=` option instead: `texcount ... -out=outfile`.

Another alternative is to make a file `texcount.bat` as described in the [TeXcount FAQ](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#html) or using the [provided script file](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/utilities.html) ([texcount.bat](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/view.php?file=texcount.bat)) which you'd probably have to modify a bit to run. This could do the word count and open the output in a browser, which is the solution I tend to use.

Comment: I expect you are right @Einar - I am sure it is running the one contained in MiKTeX - interesting to know that is an old version. I don't really need to run it through TeXnicCenter now I have it working via other means, but it's useful to know about `-out` - I might try it just to see if it works for me. Since I have installed texcount.pl (the _3_0_0_24 was the directory name, not the perl itself), I would prefer to run the newer version - I guess I need to work out how to fiddle with "$PATH" on Windoze. I asked for .pl to be associated with perl so should be OK on that front...

Comment: Just an update. `-out` does now write something to the file, but it is just a list of the formatting for verbose output: for some reason the actual counts do not appear - I expect it is not picking up the file specified by "%pm". On the other hand, it does seem to be version 3.0 so I am not going to bother trying to work out how to use my downloaded version

Comment: No that's wrong. The texcount.exe in miktex is not a "compiled version". It is a simple wrapper for a "perl texcount.pl" call (as you see by its size of only 33kb). You need perl to run it. Also in the scripts folder of miktex there is a texcount.pl (if the package has been installed correctly) and it contains the message `my $versionnumber="3.0";`. So it is version 3.0.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for the correction. I have updated the answer accordingly. Maybe my MiKTeX installation is old as it only gives me TeXcount v2.3 (even after attempting an update).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do not have a `texcount.pl` anywhere (at least, I did a file search on the whole C:\ drive) and certainly not in the scripts directory, which was the first place I looked, but I can run texcount.

Comment: @FionaSmith.  What do you get if you run in a command window `findtexmf texcount.pl`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, that found it! I do have "search subdirectories" checked, but perhaps windows has some kind of depth issue? Anyway, I am now less confused (all the documentation I saw on line also said texcount.exe was just a wrapper)

Comment: @FionaSmith Perhaps windows did hide the extension.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes I just clicked to "Include non-indexed, hidden and system files" and it has found texcount.pl, after about 10 mins search. I know much more about windows now than I did before trying to use texcount ;-)